# Yocto openssl package not installing binary files

Tags: openssl, yocto

I have `IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " openssl"` in my local.conf.

I am building rootfs by executing `bitbake console-image`.

But It does not copy openssl binaries to rootfs. As I see it has a subpackage called openssl-bin but don't know how to force installation of this package.

Yocto Version: thud

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding openssl-bin to IMAGE_INSTALL_append doesn't work?

You can also write an openssl_%.bbappend with a do_install_append() function in order to "manually" select and install the binaries you need.

Comment: Adding openssl-bin to IMAGE_INSTALL_append didn't work before, but after your answer I tried again & now it's OK. I don't know how but it worked. Thanks.